# How do i parse a Google Voice email address with PHP/Regex?

Tags: php, regex, google-voice

I would like to extract `16197226146` from the following string using PHP:

```
"(480) 710-6186" <18583894531.16197226146.S7KH51hwhM@txt.voice.google.com>
```

Could someone please help me with the regex please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<\d*?\.(\d+)`

```
<    Match "<"
\d   Match digits
   *    0 or more times
   ?    Lazy, take as little as possible
\.   Match a "."
(    Capture
   \d   Match digits
   +    1 or more times
)    Stop capturing
```

That matches the second number after a `.`. The match is in group 1.

```
if (preg_match("/<\d*?\.(\d+)/", $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

[You can play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?316r7).

Comment: Perfect! And yes, thanks for the tool! I had to remove the`<` - worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode.

```
$value = "(480) 710-6186"<18583894531.16197226146.S7KH51hwhM@txt.voice.google.com>";

$result  = explode('.', $value);
echo $result[1]; // is 16197226146
```